# 1500 euros /month Stipend enough for surviving in Strasbourg City?

Tags: france

I am an Indian. I will be going for PhD in Strasbourg University. The stipend is 1500 euros/month. I do not expect any money from any other sources apart from stipend itself.

Will I be able to survive there and probably do a bit more than just survival?

Comment: Question about long-term migration should be placed on our sister website - Expats.StackExchange.

Comment: Fits better in Expats.SE, in addition to that, you need to mention more details, such as is accommodation included, etc.?

Comment: Surviving should be no problem, that's more than the minimum wage and many people do it. A couple of things to think about: You will be a student, explore all potential advantages (discounts, subsidies for accommodation, eating at the university, etc.). Also, what happens after your stipend runs out? It's not unusual to need more time to finish a PhD.